# Swift nsinputstream not giving me the correct data from Trimble

Tags: swift, nsinputstream

I've developed this for the android and simply used a *bufferedreader* and `br.readline()` and the code properly interpreted the data coming through.

I should be getting data that looks like this:

```
$GPRMC,191830.00,A,4159.87613,N,09338.29258,W,0.065,303.4,270815,0.8,E,D*21
```

what I am getting is data that looks like this:

(WK#  (yup that's it)

The code in viewDidLoad()

```
if accessoryList.count > 0 {
        println(accessoryList[0].description)
        session = EASession(accessory: accessoryList[0] as! EAAccessory, forProtocol: "com.trimble.mcs.gnss")
        if session != nil {
            inputStream = session.inputStream
            //outputStream = session.outputStream

            inputStream.delegate = self
            inputStream.scheduleInRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
            inputStream.open()
        }
    }
    else {
    }
```

and my stream function()

```
func stream(aStream: NSStream, handleEvent eventCode: NSStreamEvent) {

    let inStream = aStream as? NSInputStream

    switch (eventCode){
    case NSStreamEvent.OpenCompleted:
        NSLog("Stream opened")
        break
    case NSStreamEvent.HasBytesAvailable:
        NSLog("HasBytesAvailable")
        let bufferSize = 128
        var buffer = [UInt8](count: bufferSize, repeatedValue: 0)
        if(session.inputStream!.hasBytesAvailable) {
            let result :Int = session.inputStream!.read(&buffer, maxLength: bufferSize)
            if(result > 0){
                var output = NSString(bytes: &buffer, length: bufferSize, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                if(output != nil) {
                    println(output!)
                }
            }
        }
        break
    case NSStreamEvent.ErrorOccurred:
        NSLog("ErrorOccurred")
        break
    case NSStreamEvent.EndEncountered:
        NSLog("EndEncountered")
        break
    default:
        NSLog("unknown.")
    }
}
```

Is there something I'm missing?  I'm getting data, it's just not in english.  I know that the encoding is UTF8.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there are a couple of ways you can make a paired connection.  The Trimble is sending me 2 streams of data, one is written in binary and the other is nmea strings.  I haven't figured out how to get the nmea strings on an iphone, but I would prefer the more accurate binary values.  Here's a link to the description and explanation on how to interpret the binary data http://www.trimble.com/OEM_ReceiverHelp/v4.85/en/GSOFmessages_Overview.html.

I rewrote the code with some help:

```
case NSStreamEvent.HasBytesAvailable:
        NSLog("HasBytesAvailable")
        let bufferSize = 512
        var buffer = Array<UInt8>(count: bufferSize, repeatedValue: 0)
        if(session.inputStream!.hasBytesAvailable) {
            let result :Int = session.inputStream!.read(&buffer, maxLength: bufferSize)
            print(buffer[0..<result].map{String(format: "%02x", Int32($0))}.joinWithSeparator(" "))
        }
        break
```

I hope this helps anyone else hunting for this answer.  This code prints it out in 2 byte arrays.